# How to adjust the column width of an item on a contribution receipt?

Tags: receipts, smarty, css

As it can be seen from screenshot below, the "QTY" column is too close to the "Donation amount" and often times it can be mistaken as "1081" instead of "108". Is there a way to adjust the column width of QTY on a contribution receipt? I have tried add `style="min-width:20%"` but doesnt work. Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would be nice to have border for tables to avoid confusion. you can add css in your message template, either it can be inline or using  tag

```
{literal}
  <style>
    .button-group {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 5px !important;
      margin-bottom: 5px !important;
   }
  </style>
{/literal}
```

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt help? is button-group an existing class within message template?

Comment: i just provided an example how you can add style in message template